# Assign type selector after class name in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to add the HTML element selector after the class name?

So instead of:

```
a.class {color: pink;}
```

the other way round:

```
.class?a {color: pink;}
```

Comment: `.class a {...}` but it will be a selector of `<a>` that is  child of .class

Comment: @Banzay that would select any link children of .class

Comment: No, there is no way. Why would you want that?

Comment: Alvaro, why do you need such kind of notation?

Comment: I'd assume OP wants to neaten his code by grouping class definitions together instead of element definitions. Instead of doing `a.myClass {} div.myClass {}`, you could (hypothetically) do `myClass?a {} myClass?div {}`, etc.

Comment: @pol I was building with stylus some selectors, and found this would be handy not to repeat the selector. I can repeat and do it the normal way, but I was wondering if there is such way.

Comment: Aah, stylus the stylish fork :) .. It should be possible with the matching pseudo selector, or negation. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, a simple selector always starts with a type selector or a universal selector. In other words, you can't have a type selector, such as `a`, follow a class selector.

From the [CSS selector specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) regarding the syntax of selectors (emphasis added):

> [**4. Selector syntax**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax)
>
> A selector is a chain of one or more [sequences of simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sequence) separated by [combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators). One [pseudo-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) may be appended to the last sequence of simple selectors in a selector.
>
> A sequence of [simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a [combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators). **It always begins with a [type selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) or a universal selector.** No other type selector or [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector) is allowed in the sequence.

To clarify that last point, the presence of a universal selector is implied in cases such as `.class` (which means that `.class` is equivalent to `*.class`).

> [**6.2. Universal selector**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector)
>
> If a universal selector represented by `*` (i.e. without a namespace prefix) is not the only component of a [sequence of simple selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sequence) or is immediately followed by a pseudo-element, then the `*` may be omitted and the universal selector's presence implied.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS syntax dictates that first comes the element and then other identifiers (id, classes, attributes).
However, there is a way to write it in reverse notation, but the CSS will be longer.

1. The **matching** selector:
   For Firefox 4+ `:-moz-any(selector1, selector2, etc)`
   For Chrome 15+, Safari 5+, Opera 15+ `:-webkit-any()`
   IE/Edge have no support.
   The new specification would be: `:matches()`, which isn't supported by any browser yet.
   [Selectors Level 4 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo)
   [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any)

2. Using negation `:not()`:
   With this, you can choose element to ignore
   `:not(div)`
   To ignore multiple elements, you will need to use `:not` multiple times:
   `:not(div):not(span)`

Check this demo:

```css
.one { background-color: green; }
.two { background-color: blue; }

/*The matching selector must be written separately for each vendor*/
/*If we use comma, the whole rule is ignored by the browser*/
.one:-moz-any(a) {
  background-color: red; color: white;
}
.one:-webkit-any(a) {
  background-color: red; color: white;
}

.two:not(div) {
  background-color: orange; color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<a class="one">link</a><br>
<a class="two">link2</a><br>
```

Comment: Very interesting the **:-webkit-any(a)** / -moz. I won't be using it as it is limited for certain browsers, complex, etc. but it is very nice to know there is such way. Thank you.

Comment: "IE/Edge don't support the old specification." There *is no* old specification. :any() was never in any spec. It started off as a vendor-specific feature meant for internal use before it was specced as :matches(). That's why the prefixes are there - to dissuade authors from trying to use them in public-facing CSS, because they were never intended to be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

No, that syntax does not exist. For what purpose would you like to use it?

Here's a full list of the CSS selector options, through CSS3: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp